# Spark on Kubernetes, is it humanly possible to get it working?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

Is there anywhere I can find a step-by-step guide to installing and running Spark on Kubernetes that actually works?

The instructions I've found online are laughably inaccurate and seem to miss out on numerous steps, or just have a ton of assumed knowledge. I've tried the bitnami helm charts, they install and 3 workers get created, but nothing runs. They get as far as the driver reporting that "Initial job has not accepted any resources" then when checking their git they just seem to have given up on that working.

I've tried the standard install docs, they are barely readable and have nothing on how to really install it, I've set up the docker images. I muddled my way through and managed to set up a service account after their "step by step" instructions failed. However, now it just creates an infinite death spiral of 3 pods at a time which all fail with "Unable to create executor due to URI has an authority component". Is it connecting to the master node I set up with the helm chart? Yes, because there were no install instructions for the standard method.

I know it's open source so can't expect someone to be able to document things but by this point you would think someone could just write down the steps in order???

I have a 4 node kuberentes cluster with complete admin access if that helps. This can't be as hard as it seems.

Comment: This is usually the case with projects that have been decommissioned. It is actually not worth it, in my opinion to try and get them to work. Instead you can move to a project that is more active and has better support. Is it necessary that you _MUST_ use spark? I would suggest you consider alternatives.

Comment: I say this also because you could have problems with:
1. spark version not compatible with the operating system version
2. k8s version not compatible with the spark version
and it is not worth the effort to try and find an older version that is compatible with spark.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you don't try to run spark itself and handle it manually and move to a more `Kubernetes native` approach instead. For instance, you can use the following `Spark k8s operator` which will allow you to manage your spark workloads more declaratively and is the current/better approach than simply trying to run spark as a workload on k8s, which is already giving you so much pain.

[Here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator) is the GitHub repo for the spark operator. And operators are the recommended way to add functionality to Kubernetes. This approach has a lot of benefits, including:

1. Stability of the functionality that is added.
2. Easier debugging. Since it is an operator (technically a k8s resource) you will have access to all the k8s utilities and constructs that will help you debug your issues.
3. It can be maintained easily.
4. A declarative approach favors automation and improves maintainability of your project.